# Add manufacturers name to a category listing

Tags: magento

I want to add the manufacturers name to a category listing. Found this thread, http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1610/P15/#t42109 but I can´t get it to work.

In the catalog.xml I have added

```
<action method="addAttribute"><attribute>manufacturer</attribute></action>
```

after

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

in both section

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
```

and

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
```

In my list.phtml I have tried

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

which gave an empty result
and

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

which gave the result "No"

I´m running version 1.5.1.0

Comment: If I dump the product with print_r($_product); in the listing, shouldn´t the <action method... from the catalog.xml put the manufacturer in the list of attributes?

Answer (score 0):

1) Simply put the required to "YES" via the magento backoffice

2) Reindex

3) It will work (either `$_product->getManufacturer(), $_product->getdata("manufacturer") or echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')`)

Regards,
Kenny

Answer (score 0):

You need to set *Used in Product Listing* to Yes for the 'manufacturer' attribute and the code will work just fine.